# I want to redirect a url having multiple query string using rewriterule apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

`abc.com/xyz/nx/crm?eId=1a&oid=A3E4B-9477-A1D2&g_fid=5BDC-6C223C8332E1&n_id=xyz`

I want that if there is n number of (&)query string it will redirect to the same page irrespective of number of query string in url like if I want to redirect this to `/abc/en-us/xyz/nx/crm_eId_%1.html [PT,L]`

Used below but it didnt work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^eId=(.*)?(&.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^/xyz/nx/crm /abc/en-us/xyz/nx/crm_eId_%1.html [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^eId=([^&]+)(.*)

RewriteRule ^/xyz/nx/crm /abc/en-us/xyz/nx/crm_eId_%1.html [QSA,PT,L]

This works for multiple query string in the urls.